# iTextSharp - Document has no pages when working with table

Tags: .net, vb.net, itext

```
    Dim doc As New Document()
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream("Invoice.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    doc.Open()

    Dim table As New PdfPTable(6)
    table.WidthPercentage = 110

    Dim cellDate As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("9/10/14"))
    cellDate.Colspan = 2
    table.AddCell(cellDate)

    Dim cellCompany As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Company Inc." & vbNewLine & _
                                                   "Sales Person" & vbNewLine & _
                                                   "123 S 150th Road" & vbNewLine & _
                                                   "Somecity, NA 12345" & vbNewLine & _
                                                    "405.555.9999"))
    cellDate.Colspan = 2
    table.AddCell(cellCompany)

    Dim cellInvoiceNo As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("12345"))
    cellDate.Colspan = 2
    table.AddCell(cellInvoiceNo)

    doc.Add(table)
    doc.Close()
```

after executing this code I get a "document has no pages" error.
I have found a few others with this error but their issue was that they forgot to add the table to the document, So I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

More detail:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=The document has no pages.
  Source=itextsharp
  StackTrace:
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPages.WritePageTree()
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
       at iTextSharp.text.Document.Close()
       at {Project}.Form1.btnDOIT_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\James\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\{Project}\Form1.vb:line 78
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at {Project}.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are setting the page size..

Comment: @DJKRAZE defaults kick in.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking iTextSharp to create a 12 column table but you are only using 4 of those columns, 3 cells with 1 cell spanned 2 columns.

```
Dim table As New PdfPTable(12)
```

Related, you probably have a glitch or a copy and paste error because you keep settings the `colspan` on the same variable over and over.

```
cellDate.Colspan = 2 ''//This is in the code three times
```

iTextSharp ignores incomplete rows by default and since you only have a single row and it isn't complete you have zero content.

You can change your column count in the constructor to what you're actually going to use:

```
Dim table As New PdfPTable(4)
```

If my assumption about your typo is correct then you probably actually want this when fixed:

```
Dim table As New PdfPTable(6)
```

If you've got a valid reason to not actually use the same number of columns that you specify you can use this right before adding the table to the document to "fill in the blanks".

```
table.CompleteRow()
```

Comment: You are quite right that my column widths did not line up with my table size, They were originally 3-6-3 but In my struggle to determine my problem I didn't correct them before posting this question. --Now that I have changed it to a table with a width of 6, I still get an error...                                     An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in itextsharp.dll

Additional information: The document has no pages.

Comment: You still only have four columns because you are settings the `colspan` on the `cellDate` variable over and over instead of on `cellDate` and cellInvoiceNo`

Comment: Well... You have no idea how stupid I feel right now... Thank you for the help...

Comment: We've all done it! 10 hours of staring at broken code can often be solved in 10 seconds by a second set of eyes!

Answer (score 1):

Just for a completion of possible causes, this also occurs when iTextSharp fails to find the path to your TTF font resource.

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(pathToUniFont, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

It remembers it when tries to close the document... (Arrrrrr...)

And here are some more unusual reasons:

http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/document-has-no-pages-grrr-td906.html

Comment: Some good ideas to pursue in the link. My problem (same error message) ended up being a .DLL (completely unrelated to iText) that was present in local builds, but missing on the build server.